# how to pass ggplot parameters through a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple code that creates a combined barplot and line plot with two axes. I wanted to make this code dynamic so that I can pass the columns to plot as parameters of a function. Here is the code outside the function,it works fine:

```
data <- data.frame(group = LETTERS[1:5],    # Create example data
                   sample = c(1000, 800, 1200, 900, 800),
                   responses1 = c(0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8),
                   responses2 = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3)
                   )

ggp1 <- ggplot(data) +                     
  geom_bar(aes(group, sample), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_line(aes(group, responses * max(sample), group = 1),
            col = "#1b98e0", lwd = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / max(data$sample)))

ggp1
```

Now when trying to put it in a function it becomes challenging a little bit for me:

```
plot_func <- function(var1, var2) {
  ggp1 <- ggplot(data) +                     
    geom_bar(aes(group, var1), stat = "identity") + 
    geom_line(aes(group, var2 * max(var1), group = 1),
              col = "#1b98e0", lwd = 3) + 
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / max(data[[var1]])))
  
  ggp1
}
```

Comment: If you want to pass them in unquoted you need to quote and unquote using either the older notation `!!sym(x)` or the newer `{{x}}`.

Comment: I tried using {{var1}} and {{var2}} but it doesn't work if that is what you mean.

Comment: Can you show the way you define when you call it in `plot_func()`? It should be `plot_func(responses1)`

Comment: Your first block of code plotting outside a function also doesn't work because `responses` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: that's a typo. I meant that if you use responses1 or responses2 it should work.

Comment: group column is always in the data so it's not the problem. The other two var1 and var2 are selected by the user. So they are two character variables that represent the name of two columns in the data. following your suggestion I used plot_func(var1="sample",var2="responses2"). but it returns an error.

Comment: rror in (~"responses2") * max(~"sample") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Ok - will check. But just FYI it's a bad practice to write a function that relies on a specific dataset being defined in your global environment. Much better practice to pass the data to your function so it's self contained.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried to give a simple reproducible example. The real code is in a complex shiny app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing var1 and var1 unquoted, you could try something like this:

```
plot_func <- function(df, var1, var2) {
  ggp1 <- ggplot(df) +                     
    geom_bar(aes(group, {{var1}}), stat = "identity") +
    geom_line(aes(group, {{var2}} * max({{var1}}), group = 1), col = "#1b98e0", lwd = 3) + 
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / max(df %>% pull({{var1}}))))
  ggp1
}
```

Then try:

```
plot_func(data,sample, responses1)
```

On the other hand, if var1 and var2 are like this "sample" and "responses1", respectively, you can define the function this way:

```
plot_func2 <- function(df, var1, var2) {

  var1_max = max(data[[var1]])
  data$line_y = data[[var2]]*var1_max
  
  ggp1 <- ggplot(df) +                     
    geom_bar(aes_string("group", var1), stat = "identity") +
    geom_line(aes_string("group", "line_y", "group" = 1), col = "#1b98e0", lwd = 3) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / var1_max))
  ggp1
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
var1="sample"
var2="responses1"
plot_func2(data,var1,var2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the working example. I think I wasn't very clear about my problem. I don't know the parameters sample and responses1 to pass them this way: plot_func(data,sample, responses1). I store the chosen two columns selected by the user in two variables var1 and var2 and I wanted to be able to pass them directly like plot_func(data, var1, var2).

Comment: got it. sorry I did not understand

Comment: From your app, are the variables `character`s? That changes how you want to pull them into your function.

Comment: The user has the list of variables in two dropdown menus, so he selects the var1 and var2 which is are strings (names of columns). After that, I just should plug those two selected values into the function.